# I cannt make work install() function in custom module opencart

Tags: php, sql, model, module, opencart

i am making custom module for opencart,
and now i am trying to create DB table at module instalation.
And when i am installing module, it is not giving any arror, module is working, but in DB doesnt exist table.

At start i was tring to make it using model

```
public function install() {
    $this->load->model('module/collectionfilter');
    $this->model_module_collectionfilter->createCollectionfilter();
 }
```

But it was not working so i changed a little bit, making it simpliest

```
        <?php
    class ControllerModuleCollectionfilter extends Controller {
     private $error = array();

   public function install() {
    $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT           EXISTS`".DB_PREFIX."collectionfilter` (
                      `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                      `attr_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`attr_name`)
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
   }
```

But it still not working, i tried make it in phpMyAdmin, with

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_collectionfilter` (
                      `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                      `attr_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`attr_name`)
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And table was created, so i dont know why its failing, somebady can help me??

```
public function install() {
    //$this->load->model('module/collectionfilter');
    //$this->model_module_collectionfilter->createCollectionfilter();
    $string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "collectionfilter` (
                      `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                      `attr_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (`attr_name`)
                      ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    $try = $this->db->query($string);
    echo $try;
}
public function uninstall() {

    $this->load->model('module/collectionfilter');
    $this->model_module_collectionfilter->dropCollectionfilter();
}
public function index() {
    $this->load->language('module/collectionfilter');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('collectionfilter', $this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('module/collectionfilter', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/collectionfilter', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    if (isset($this->request->post['collectionfilter_status'])) {
        $data['collectionfilter_status'] = $this->request->post['collectionfilter_status'];
    } else {
        $data['collectionfilter_status'] = $this->config->get('collectionfilter_status');
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/collectionfilter.tpl', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/collectionfilter')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
 }
```

Solved, i was. It was hosting and my partner, I was working on old DB, and site was on different.

Comment: Please specify the file name of function : 'install' .

Comment: It stay in collectionfilter.php
in folder module
In actually function in executing, but no result in database

Comment: Your first effort was right - you should do database manipulation inside model files.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your install function it is working fine and creating table in database.

Log in to phpMyAdmin in incognito window and check if your table exist or not. Sometimes phpMyAdmin don't show new tables until you use its refresh button.

**Controller:admin/controller/module/collectionfilter.php**

```
private $error = array();

public function install() {
    //$this->load->model('module/collectionfilter');
    //$this->model_module_collectionfilter->createCollectionfilter();
    $string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "collectionfilter` (
                  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                  `attr_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`attr_name`)
                  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    $try = $this->db->query($string);
    echo $try;
    die();
}

public function uninstall() {

    $this->load->model('module/collectionfilter');
    $this->model_module_collectionfilter->dropCollectionfilter();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('module/collectionfilter');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('collectionfilter', $this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('module/collectionfilter', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/collectionfilter', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    if (isset($this->request->post['collectionfilter_status'])) {
        $data['collectionfilter_status'] = $this->request->post['collectionfilter_status'];
    } else {
        $data['collectionfilter_status'] = $this->config->get('collectionfilter_status');
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/collectionfilter.tpl', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/collectionfilter')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}

}
?>
```

**Language:admin/language/english/module/collectionfilter.php**

```
<?php
    // Heading
    $_['heading_title']       = 'Collection Filter';

    // Text
    $_['text_module']         = 'Modules';
    $_['text_success']        = 'Success: You have modified module Google Talk!';
    $_['text_content_top']    = 'Content Top';
    $_['text_content_bottom'] = 'Content Bottom';
    $_['text_column_left']    = 'Column Left';
    $_['text_column_right']   = 'Column Right';

    // Entry
    $_['entry_code']          = 'Google Talk Code:<br /><span class="help">Goto <a href="http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/New" target="_blank"><u>Create a Google Talk chatback badge</u></a> and copy &amp; paste the generated code into the text box.</span>';
    $_['entry_layout']        = 'Layout:';
    $_['entry_position']      = 'Position:';
    $_['entry_status']        = 'Status:';
    $_['entry_sort_order']    = 'Sort Order:';

    // Error
    $_['error_permission']    = 'Warning: You do not have permission to modify module Google Talk!';
    $_['error_code']          = 'Code Required';
    ?>
```

Template:admin/view/template/module/collectionfilter.tpl

```
            <?php echo $header; ?>
        <div id="content">
          <div class="breadcrumb">
            <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
            <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
          <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
          <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="heading">
              <h1><img src="view/image/module.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
              <div class="buttons"><a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a><a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
                <table id="module" class="list">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_layout; ?></td>
                      <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_position; ?></td>
                      <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></td>
                      <td class="right"><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <?php $module_row = 0; ?>
                  <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
                  <tbody id="module-row<?php echo $module_row; ?>">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][layout_id]">
                          <?php foreach ($layouts as $layout) { ?>
                          <?php if ($layout['layout_id'] == $module['layout_id']) { ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $layout['layout_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $layout['name']; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $layout['layout_id']; ?>"><?php echo $layout['name']; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select></td>
                      <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][position]">
                          <?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_top') { ?>
                          <option value="content_top" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="content_top"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                          <?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_bottom') { ?>
                          <option value="content_bottom" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="content_bottom"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                          <?php if ($module['position'] == 'column_left') { ?>
                          <option value="column_left" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_column_left; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="column_left"><?php echo $text_column_left; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                          <?php if ($module['position'] == 'column_right') { ?>
                          <option value="column_right" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_column_right; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="column_right"><?php echo $text_column_right; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select></td>
                      <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][status]">
                          <?php if ($module['status']) { ?>
                          <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                          <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                          <?php } else { ?>
                          <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                          <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </select></td>
                      <td class="right"><input type="text" name="filter_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][sort_order]" value="<?php echo $module['sort_order']; ?>" size="3" /></td>
                      <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#module-row<?php echo $module_row; ?>').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <?php $module_row++; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="4"></td>
                      <td class="left"><a onclick="addModule();" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_module; ?></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var module_row = <?php echo $module_row; ?>;

        function addModule() {  
                html  = '<tbody id="module-row' + module_row + '">';
                html += '  <tr>';
                html += '    <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[' + module_row + '][layout_id]">';
                <?php foreach ($layouts as $layout) { ?>
                html += '      <option value="<?php echo $layout['layout_id']; ?>"><?php echo addslashes($layout['name']); ?></option>';
                <?php } ?>
                html += '    </select></td>';
                html += '    <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[' + module_row + '][position]">';
                html += '      <option value="content_top"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?></option>';
                html += '      <option value="content_bottom"><?php echo $text_content_bottom; ?></option>';
                html += '      <option value="column_left"><?php echo $text_column_left; ?></option>';
                html += '      <option value="column_right"><?php echo $text_column_right; ?></option>';
                html += '    </select></td>';
                html += '    <td class="left"><select name="filter_module[' + module_row + '][status]">';
            html += '      <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>';
            html += '      <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>';
            html += '    </select></td>';
                html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="filter_module[' + module_row + '][sort_order]" value="" size="3" /></td>';
                html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#module-row' + module_row + '\').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>';
                html += '  </tr>';
                html += '</tbody>';

                $('#module tfoot').before(html);

                module_row++;
        }
        //--></script> 
        <?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: Actually i tried relog in phpmyadmin, still not working.
You have tried it in opencart??

Comment: Yes, I tried in Opencart. I suggest you to replace $this->db->query with print_r and add die(); after print_r statement. Then try to reinstall and run the printed query in Phpmyadmin. Chances are you have some typo in query.

Comment: Well, now i am actually trying 
`$string = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '" . DB_PREFIX . "collectionfilter' (
                          'category_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
                          'attr_name' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY ('attr_name')
                          ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
  
$try = $this->db->query($string);
  
echo $try;`
First i tryed return $string, and run it in php my admin, and it worked.
And now its returning 1, what mean no erros as i know, i wrote to hosting support, may be it some php config problem.

Comment: Why don't you try it first in localhost. I don't think it has something to do with hosting. Can you post complete controller code here?

Comment: Sure, i cannt put it in coment, so it goes in my first post.

Comment: Your function is working fine for me on OC 1.5.6.4.  I also have added code of controller, language and template. If it still don't add table in your database, please have some sleep and try it after few hours  ;)

Comment: Sorry for losed time. It was hosting, or better saing my partner and hosting. He changed BD and didnt sayed me nothing, so i was looking older version, and site have another new DB. Sry for losing your time.

Comment: No problem, I was just twitching my fingers ;)

Comment: @jokermanx You should mark this answer as correct so Nitin gets the points and people know it's solved.